How do I turn the text within a Gridview cell, into a link, which when clicked on executes an SQL Query

The application is coded in ASP.NET web forms. Basically, I am trying to Turn the values within the Gridview cells into Hyperlinks that when clicked on, Execute a Query. Here is some code which gets the Data into the Gridview cells
if (pastdue.Rows[i][0].ToString().Contains("DFM"))            
{
    pastduedfm++;
    GridView1.Rows[3].Cells[1].Text = pastduedfm.ToString();
}

Also here is the HTML code in the .aspx file for the Gridview itself and the code for the Datasource:
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>

GridView1.DataSource = Orders;
GridView1.DataBind();

I am not redirecting to another page upon the click. Basically, when the user clicks on the links/cells, a query is executed for example:
select * from orders where orders.tooling_type =DFM and orders.status like '%Past Due%'

I've already figured out storing the query results in a DataTable and assigning that DataTable as the Datasource for another Gridview. I'm good there.
I'd just like to know how I can turn the cells into hyperlinks and possibly go about creating the function when the link is clicked to execute a query?
Thank you.

If i remember it correctly, on server side you will put a control in the grid to render as.

It's easy. You can add a LinkButton to a TemplateField. Then add a RowCommand to the GridView to capture the PostBack in the backend.
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
  CssClass="table table-bordered" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column A">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dbfield01")%>' CommandName="QueryDb"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("dbfield01")%>' CssClass="d-block text-decoration-none" />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column B">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dbfield02")%>' CommandName="QueryDb"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("dbfield02")%>' CssClass="d-block text-decoration-none" />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

Then the RowCommand method in the backend
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "QueryDb")
    {
        //this is to show it works only, always use parameratized queries!
        Label1.Text = $"SELECT * FROM MyDb WHERE column = '{e.CommandArgument}'";

        //run your query here
    }
}

The d-block text-decoration-none are Bootstrap classes to make the link the full size of the table cell.
